# What is the time complexity of this Regex pattern match?

Tags: python, regex

In python:

```
word = "hello"
yes = re.search("h.llo", word)
```

What would be the complexity of this regex search?

I'm trying to understand if regex would compute this differently, than say just trying out the 26 alphabet letters as the "." and comparing it with word. And if so, how would it do it differently?

*Edit: `word` variable would be an input in the function, not defined directly

Answer (score 2):

Time complexity normally refers to number of primitive operations performed in terms of the size of variable and arbitrarily large input (here e.g. the text passed to `re.search`). It is customarily denoted as O(<expression>) where the expression involves the input size *n*, examples being O(n) or O(n^2). Since in your case the text is known in advance, the time complexity of the search is technically constant, or O(1).

If the input text were not given in advance, the time complexity would be O(n), meaning that the worst-case number of operations performed would scale linearly with the size of the text. The constant of that linear scaling, which is what you are asking about, is *not* a thing time complexity is normally concerned about.

A competent regex engine would not try 26 comparisons (in fact 256 because `.` matches non-letters, or who knows how many taking Unicode into account) to match the `.`, it would just not compare that letter of the string to anything in the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the implementation.  Many regex libraries will use a variant on finite automata, which would match the above regex in `O(|word|)` to `O(|word|*|regex|)` time.  None of them would "try out 26 letters", because `.` actually matches **anything**, not alphanumeric, and this would quickly become impossibly slow (how would you match `.*`, by calculating all possible strings? =D).

I would guess most implementations would only use 5-9 total comparisons to determine that your word matches.

Comment: I see! I'm not familiar with finite automata, though may I assume that, essentially, regex usually uses some complex algorithms for the permutations such that it makes it linear time, instead of factorial ("manual" permutations).

Comment: Say if I'm trying to search a pattern with dots in it, in another word, what would be the time complexity here? I'm thinking it would depend on the number of dots in the pattern but also the number of letters in the word.

Comment: @FryingPan Time complexity doesn't mean what you think it means, see my answer for a short overview. Also the number of dots doesn't make the pattern harder to match against, if anything it makes it _easier_ because some characters don't need to be compared. On the other hand, something like `.*` does makes the pattern harder to match against because it requires arbitrary backtracking in the worst case - perhaps you were referring to that?